# copy installed file from blackberry and re-install it

Tags: security, blackberry

I've developed a blackberry app and i've installed it ona bb device. say i loose the phone and someone finds it and wants to copy my application and install it on another device. is it possibile? can u copy the file from the device and re-install it on another device? or is it only possible to install the app through bb desktop manager and source code? (excluding market ofcource). thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. You can prevent this by having some value needed to operate entered by the user on start up and stored in the [PersistentStore](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.html), and password protecting your device. If someone finds the device they can cause it to do a security wipe by entering the wrong password. That will delete the PersistentStore but not the software. However, if they try to copy your program to another device it won't run because they can't copy the data. If you are really concerned then you could base the data on a cryptographic process.

A simpler way, if you are only running the program on your personal device is to check for the [PIN](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html#getDeviceId%28%29) and compare it to the value of the PIN of the device that should be running it. That will stop them from copying to a new device, but won't stop them from running the program on your found device.

Comment: As Richard answered - yes, it's possible to get app from device and reinstall to another one - http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do;jsessionid=EFE448E3CF009FE73091239957A1F73C?externalId=KB25524&sliceId=1&cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&noCount=true&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl